Is it better to have one POST endpoint and be called multiple times or two POST endpoints one for creating one and the other for creating multiple?
Let's say we're creating a message. Some users can only send a message to one other user; meanwhile others have the possibility to send a message to one or more other users.
What would be better for this problem?
One endpoint to create one or multiple messages with one call /users/messages/create
One endpoint to create one message, but being called multiple times /users/:userId/messages
Two endpoints:
One for being called only once to create one message /users/:userId/messages
One for being called only once only to create multiple messages /users/multiple-users/messages
I know this is somewhat confusing as to why I am asking because /users/messages/create is just better, but I want to know what would be better for other developers. I also want to know the better practices for writing a RESTful API.
